# Mvc 4 Proxy Server/Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, proxy

I am trying to implement the Jonathon Kresner
"Asp .net Mvc 4 Proxy Server/Controller (For help with Cross Domain Request)" https://gist.github.com/jkresner/3982746 .

Could anyone indicate how to call it from jquery please?

the coffescript call with the article [gist.github.com/jkresner](http://gist.github.com/jkresner), leaves me perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

The coffeescript basicaly says that for clients who can't connect to the remote url by themselves, swap out the specified remote URL reference (i.e. http://api.othersite.com/Widget/7 ) with a reference to http://myoriginalpagehost.com/proxy and let the server side proxy the content from the http://myoriginalpagehost.com/proxy URI over to the http://api.othersite.com/Widget/7 URL.

One thing to note on that proxy is that it appears that cache control mechanisms will likely be subverted causing a potentially significant system load.  Something to think about before boilerplate copy / paste of someones code. :-/

[This article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) discusses another solution to the proxy issue that makes use of IIS's URL rewriting mechanisms. No coding, just configuring.

Comment: One thing to note where using a ProxyController instead of URL rewriting for access to, say internal resources, is that it allows you to leverage your application's services (such as authentication) - which if I'm not mistaken IIS URL rewriting will not allow you to do directly.